# Turning off Exclusive lock in my procedure

Tags: sql, sql-update, block

I have database with multiple procedures executing on it, sometimes at the same time. I would like one of my procedures to be something like that:

-every thing that blocks other procedures as Exclusive Lock (updates, inserts, deletes etc.) should not do it. I want other procedures to be able to do selects on the same data. (i heard of NOLOCK parameter but i can't change code of all that selects in other procedures.

Is there something that will allow my procedure to do update/delete/insert that won't block my data  with Exclusive lock?